# How to allow only one JavaScript 'click' method to be clicked at a time while animation is executing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, click, element

When an element is clicked, a `div` slides off the screen into the center. When another element is clicked, other `div` in the center slides off the screen and another `div` slides in.

The issue occurs when another element is clicked before the initial `div` has the time to slide to the center of the screen.

```
$('#about').click(function(){
   /* makes any visible div slide out and slides in the 'about' div */ });

$('#contact').click(function(){
   /* makes any visible div slide out and slides in the 'contact' div */ });
```

In other words, when you click `about` and right away click `contact` then they both slide in inconsistently.

*I already tried "attrRemove", "unbind", "off"... and although they work to disable clicks, I cannot enable them again.*

Comment: can u include the function code for each click

Comment: I am not totally clear. Do you want your click to work only when your animation is complete?

Comment: use timeout or delay function

Comment: Precisely, if 'about' is clicked, for the 1 second that it take for the div to slide in, 'contact' shouldn't be allowed to be clicked. After the animation is complete, then can 'contact' be clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could approach this is through the use of a variable that indicates if an action is currently in effect. If you want to queue the event (so you don't entirely disregard the click (as the example below is doing), then the code could be modified to add it to a queue of some sort.

```
var slideInProgress = false;

$('#about').click(function(){
    if (!slideInProgress) {
        slideInProgress = true;
        $("#slider").slideToggle(5000, function(){
        slideInProgress = false;
    });
  }
});
```

A very simple, quickly put together Fiddle for this example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/t8tcr0rp/

Comment: Wow! This actually worked! The only thing I changed was placed the `slideInProgress = false;` in a separate `setTimeout` and delayed it until the slide executed! Thanks **P Walker**!

Answer (score 0):

This code may help.

```
function aboutFunc() {
  $('#about').off('click');
  $('#contact').off('click');

  //do your stuff

  $('#about').on('click', aboutFunc);
  $('#contact').on('click', contactFunc);
}

function contactFunc() {
  $('#about').off('click');
  $('#contact').off('click');

  //do your stuff

  $('#about').on('click', aboutFunc);
  $('#contact').on('click', contactFunc);
}


$('#about').on('click', aboutFunc);
$('#contact').on('click', contactFunc);
```